# Import Activity in date variables

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-import

I created an import activity to import a csv with today's date file on our FTP using date variables.
Currently, three csv files with different date ("test_20200313.csv", "test_20200312.csv" and "test_20200314.csv") on the FTP and the file naming pattern determines "test_20200312.csv", not "test_20200314.csv".

What should i do for the file naming pattern to determine the csv of today's date when multiple csv with different dates exist on FTP?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming 'our FTP' is your Enhanced FTP provided with your Salesforce Marketing Cloud account?

If so, you can do what I think you're trying to achieve in a number of ways. Firstly, if you're just wanting to manually run an Import Activity or you're running it in a scheduled automation, you can [use personalization strings to substitute the date variables](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_file_naming_patterns.htm&type=5) in your file name. For example, you can pick up today's file with a file name in your import activity accordingly:

```
test_%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%.csv
```

You can also restrict files considered by altering the system buffer in the advanced settings of the Import Activity. This allows you to only consider files created within a given time period, irrespective of file name.

Depending on your use case, you should also consider using a [File Drop Automation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_define_a_triggered_automation.htm&type=5). These are started immediately on arrival a new file and more often fit the purpose of processing inbound files. You can pass the name of the newly arrived file into your Import Activity using [Substitution Strings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_substitution_strings_example.htm&type=5). For example, the following used for the file name in your Import Activity would automatically use the name of the newly arrived file:

```
%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%
```

Comment: What directory is your file in, what's the file name and what timezone are your in?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Macca. 

> I'm assuming 'our FTP' is your Enhanced FTP provided with your Salesforce Marketing Cloud account?
Yes, that's right.

Please excuse my lack of explanation. I had used personalization strings to substitute the date variables in my file name.
e.g) test_%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%.csv

But somehow "Explore file name" shows “ test_20200315.csv” while “File naming pattern sample” shows “test_20200312.csv”. 

My file is in import directory our account time zone is Japan(Tokyo, Osaka).

Comment: SFMC Servers run Central Standard Time (UTC-6). At the time you looked, 15th March hadn't started, yet, so test_20200315.csv wouldn't be picked up as it was still 14th March. You'll probably find using a file drop automation easier to work with as there are pretty limited situations I'd use the date variable in conjunction with a scheduled automation, these days.